# How to paginate data to improve loading time on fly using HTML, JQUERY, PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a table of 1400+ rows and adding approx 20 everyday getting my page slow

I am using while loop to generate table rows and columns and also some JS like this

```
<?php
$cp=0
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
        $cp++;
        $editid = $row['id'];   
       $ccperson = $row['cperson'];
?>
        <tr>
        <td span id="cperson<?php echo $cp;?>"><?php echo $ccperson;?></span></td>
        <Input id="cperson_input<?php echo $cp;?>" style="display:none"/>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        // On double click show the input box
$( "#cperson<?php echo $cp;?>" ).dblclick(function() {
    getsetEdit('<?php echo $cp;?>','<?php echo $editid;?>', 'cperson');
    });
</script>
<?php
</tr>
}
?>
```

Is it possible to get it done on a fly?

Comment: **WARNING**: It is extremely important to **NEVER** accept arbitrary query strings from the user and just run them. Find some other way to do this where you screen the input carefully, such as in checking versus a white-list of allowed values.

Comment: [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: If you want to do this, then read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Also read [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php).

Answer (score 1):

Of course your page has to slow down with time. This is because data increases with time (20 every day). Loading a bunch of data will lead to slow processing time or even collapse the browser. What you are looking for is called pagination. it is loading of data in steps. You might have seen on facebook that after scrolling down, more data is loaded. This is to avoid the problem you are experiencing. Research about pagination.You can then use AJAX JQUERY AND PHP to make it happen on fly.

Comment: is there an easy way to move to AJAX ? or add pagination?

Comment: Yes, am right busy right now. I will come back later with complete code for you.

Comment: Thanks, will be looking forward

Comment: i m waiting if u have time now to and can help me